# Does empty index bracket mean 0?

Tags: python

"len()" result should be a number, why it would equal to an empty index bracket?
Below is the Springboard coding, and it used abelow coding as recommend way compare with 'len(list_examply)==0', makes me doubt myself as a fresh beginner.

```
list_example = []
 
if len(list_example) == []:
    print("Empty")
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is that someone else's code and you're wondering why they wrote that?

Comment: By the way, you can check if a list is empty simply with `if not list_example: print("empty")`

Comment: I would expect this code to never print "Empty". Does it ever print it for you? That block is a no-op because `[]` is never equal to any integer. So this is just buggy code.

Comment: @KellyBundy, exactly, this is the Springboard coding, and it used above coding as recommend way compare with 'len(list_examply)==0', makes me doubt myself as a fresh beginner. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Either you've misunderstood the context, or the course you're taking has made an incorrect recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

> Does empty index bracket mean 0?

No, those are not equivalent.

```
In [1]: 0 == []
Out[1]: False
```

> "len()" result should be a number

It is.

> why it would equal to an empty index bracket

It wouldn't ever do that unless you've redefined the `len()` function.

Example

```
>>> len = lambda lst: [] if not lst else sum(1 for _ in lst)
>>> len([])
[]
>>> empty_lst = []
>>> len(empty_lst) == []
True
```

Answer (score 0):

`len` will return the length of the object. You might check if the length of a list is `0` by comparing the object to `[]` (empty list), but comparing the length of a list to an empty list does not make sense.

```
if list_example == []:
  ...
```

Vs.

```
if len(list_example) == 0:
  ...
```

Comment: It does not make much sense to compare a number to a list, but it can still be done and results in `False`.

Answer (score 0):

len() is a function that returns the number of elements in an object. Therefore, it requires you to pass an argument. If you are interested in checking if a list is empty, it would be more pythonic to do:

```
list_example = [] # this creates an empty list
if list_example: # will be True only if the list is not empty
    # do something....
```

Comment: It is not Pythonic at all to use `list()` rather than just `[]`.

Comment: @Chris you're right, I edited the answer.